# jquery function to access json file

Tags: jquery, json

I have a .json file and a query function in html.

html

```
<div class="op" data-articleidx="0">gold products</div>
<div class="op" data-articleidx="1">silver products</div>
<div class="op" data-articleidx="2">bronze products</div>
<div id="tt_mn"></div>
<div id="cont_mn"></div>
```

script

Use only one function for 3 divs with the same class to avoid repeat it three times:

```
$('.op').live("click", function() {
    var idx = $(this).data('articleidx');
    $.getJSON("data.json", function(data) {
        if (data && data.epigrafes && idx < data.epigrafes.length) {
            $("#tt_mn").html($("<p>" + data.epigrafes[idx].epif + "</p>"));
            $("#cont_mn").css("background-image", data.epigrafes[idx].url);
        }
    });
});
```

data.json

I'm not sure if it's a valid structure for array with 2 values.

```
{
    "epigrafes":
        [
            {
                "epif":"text 1.",
                "url":"img/ind_armario.png"
            },
            {
                "epif":"text2.",
                 "url":"ind_campana.png"
            },
            {
                "epif":"text3.",
                 "url":"ind_automata.png"
            }
        ]
}
```

The problem is that function is not able to load epif and url variables and pass to existings divs.

Comment: JSON and your code works fine. Tested. What exact problem do you face?

Comment: after i change the code,             $("#cont_mn").css("background-image", "url('"+ data.epigrafes[idx].url + "')");
it only show the first epif and the first url, neither the second neither the third.

Comment: ok sorry about that. it was a problem with the path of images. thank you. sorry again.